# Sample size of population to be representative of all names

Tags: sample, population

Im not a mathematician but need some help trying to calculate the sample size of a population needed to be indicative of the whole population with respect to the prevalence of names. Assuming sample size is 1/x total population.

This has two implications. 1) a sample large enough contain all or most of the names and 2) a sample size that if a name is found in the sample then multiplying it by x will give an accurate value for the total number of people with that name in the population.

Thanks

Comment: There is no general basis to perform such a calculation.  You need to make assumptions about the relative frequencies of the rarest names.  For instance, a population of a billion people could contain nine predominant names, covering 90% of the population, along with nearly a billion unique names.  They would both be a kind of [coupon collector's problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=coupon+collector), but the difference in required sample size is truly enormous.

Comment: This will depend on (a) how common names are in the population and (b) what you mean by accurate

Comment: If you sampled 10000 then you might expect to be able to estimate the proportion of the population having a particular name, and probably accurate to within 1 percentage point of the population for over 95% of the names, though you would probably miss most uncommon names entirely (so would say 0% for them when the true figure was positive but less than 1%)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your input whuber and Henry.

Comment: Henry, I think we have sample sizes that range from 21,000,000 which represents nearly half the population to 56,000,000 which represents on 4% of the population. So I guess we have a good chance?